# cannot install software because of authentication problem in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login, password

I am able to login into ubuntu 12.04 with the password i remember, but when i try to install a software my password is not accepted. in the user accounts it says None next to password. when i try to unlock in order to change my settings it would not let me.
here is what i tried but didn't work:

1. I changed my password through the grab menu. It seemed to accept the password, but the problem persists. furthermore, my login password didn't even change
2. I tried to install different things, using sudo, according to posts i found on the internet but it would not let me install anything

Answer (score 0):

1. Login as a normal user
2. Enable root account
   $sudo passwd root
3. switch to root account

   ## su -
4. Install packages

   ## apt-get install ...

Comment: The problem is that sudo does not recognize  the root password